# WIX - How to add command arguments to a File

Tags: command-line, wix, installation

I have made a WIX installer and i would like my main application .exe file to run using a command-line argument. I have the following line:

```
<File Id="MyApplicationExe.exe" Source="$(var.SourceFilesPath)MyApplicationExe.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
```

For the tag File i cannot find any attribute named Arguments or Command.

Does anyone know if it is even possible to add a command to a File in WIX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment you posted basically just means, that the "MyApplicationExe.exe" should be copied to the target system when your install setup is installed. It says nothing on how to start your app.

If you want a **shortcut** (in start menu) which starts you application with a specific command line, then you can just create one.

Check out the manual on creating shortcuts:
[How To: Create a Shortcut in the Start Menu](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html)

To specify command line arguments, use "Arguments" attribute of the "[Shortcut](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/shortcut.html)" element.

Comment: Okay, havent worked so much with wix. Your suggestion will work, thx!